# istio exclude service from ext-auth

Tags: authentication, filter, istio, envoyproxy

Hi guys i have set up istio on minikube and set envoy ext-auth filter on the gateways . i have two microservices running in different pods exposing virtual services /auther and /appone to outside world . the ext-auth filter i set will send every single request to /auther/auth to be authenticated and if the response is 200 let the request to pass and reach other the service it wants .
the problem is that istio is authenticating every single request to all endpoints even /auther. i want to exclude requests sent to /auther to be authenticated (cause auther service will handle the authentication itself ) .but its not working .
so here is my ext-auth filter :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: authn-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.ext_authz
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.ext_authz.v2.ExtAuthz"
            http_service:
              server_uri:
                uri: http://auther.default.svc.cluster.local
                cluster: outbound|3000||auther.default.svc.cluster.local
                timeout: 1.5s
              path_prefix: /auther/auth?user=
              authorizationRequest:
                allowedHeaders:
                  patterns:
                    - exact: "cookie"
                    - exact: "authorization"
              authorizationResponse:
                allowedClientHeaders:
                  patterns:
                    - exact: "set-cookie"
                    - exact: "authorization"
```

and here is the exception filter im trying to implement:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: bypass-filter
  namespace: default
spec:
  configPatches:
    # The first patch adds the lua filter to the listener/http connection manager
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: auther
            route:
              name: auther
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_per_filter_config:
            envoy.ext_authz:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.ext_authz.v2.ExtAuthzPerRoute
              disabled: true
```

the first filter is working just fine . but the second one which is going to exclude the auther service from the authentication ext-filter is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `@type` to `envoy.config.filter.http.ext_authz.v2.ExtAuthzPerRoute`, but the correct path is `envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute`.

Furthermore the route name must match the name in the virtual service. And it must be deployed to the `istio-system` namespace as your `authn-filter`. This config works for me:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: bypass-authn
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            route:
              name: my-route #from virtual service http route name
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          name: envoy.ext_authz_disabled
          typed_per_filter_config:
            envoy.ext_authz:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute
              disabled: true
```

Comment: which istio version are you using ?

Comment: I have used this with istio 1.6 and 1.7

Comment: i used some config as you said, i did not work

Comment: did you also deployed your deployment and service in istio-system namespace or just gateway and virtual service ?

Comment: The deployment, the service, the gateway and the virtualservice are in the same namespace of all my applications (not istio-system).

Comment: does envoy filter also in same namespace or filter is in istio-system ?

Comment: The envoy filter has to be in the istio-system namespace. You can open a new question and post all your configuration and I can have a look.